# c/c++ - convert between Unix time and the "Gregorian time"

Tags: c++, c, unix, unix-timestamp

I now have timestamps which are in microseconds since midnight, January 1st, 0 AD nominal Gregorian, after searching I noticed that some people call this "native Symbian time"? Whatever it is, I really don't know how to convert this "native Symbian time" to Unix time(time since Epoch). Is there any standard function in C/C++ to do this?

Example data are like: 63626825878362695, 63626825878363759, 63626825878657652

Comment: If it helps, that epoch is the time since midnight, January 1 1970, so you can calculate the number of seconds between current timestamp and that to recreate the epoch.

Comment: Actually, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11979655/472647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're going to need 64-bit arithmetic, or bignums.
2. If [my tool](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/src/#dateexpr) for helping me with such questions is correct, there were 62167132800 seconds between January 1, 0000 (proleptic Gregorian) and January 1, 1970.
3. To convert Unix time to Symbian, add 62167132800 and multiply by 1000000.
4. To convert Symbian time to Unix, divide by 1000000 and subtract 62167132800.

It looks like the three values you gave (which are all within the same second) are from about 10 days ago.

Comment: another good option is to use [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to get the number of `seconds between 01/01/0000 and 01/01/1970`.

Comment: @LuizEduardoF. Huh.  I tried Wolfram as you suggested, and got a different answer.  Yet I've double-checked mine, and I'm pretty sure 62167132800 is correct.  I wonder what's up with that?

Comment: I don't know the reason. Maybe I asked the wrong question? The input interpretation is: `seconds from | Saturday, January 1, 1 BC   (January 1, 0)  to  Thursday, January 1, 1970`, which gives 62167219200. The difference between 62167132800 (your answer) and 62167219200 (wolfram's answer) is 24 hours, or 86400 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

[Year 0 AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(year)) doesn't really exist ;-)

You should be able to use [ICU - International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/), as it's able to handle most common date and time conversions. Have a look at the **Converting** paragraph on the [Universal Time Scale](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/universaltimescale) page - it shows how to use ICU to convert between various date and time formats.