# Convert Date-Time to Milliseconds - C++ - cross platform

Tags: c++, posix

I want to convert a string in the format of "20160907-05:00:54.123" into milliseconds. 
I know that ***strptime*** is not available in Windows and I want to run my program in both windows and linux. I can't use third party libraries as well.
I can tokenize the string and convert it. But is there a more elegant way like using the strptime to do so?

Comment: Into milliseconds starting from when?? do you mean a UNIX epoch timestamp?

Comment: @GillBates I will be given a string in the format mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, but that's just a date, you can't convert some random date to milliseconds without knowing what the start point is.

Comment: @Will_Panda He meant which epoch do you use? to calculate number of ms from. Like "20160907-05:00:54.123 is 123 ms from "20160907-05:00:54.000

Comment: Is boost an option http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html?

Comment: @antonio "I can't use third party libraries as well".

Comment: @GillBates Sorry I misunderstood your question. Yes I am using UNIX epoch.

Comment: Can you use C++11?

Comment: Try `std::get_time`?

Comment: @Mine I tried using it. But it needs breakpoints to split apparently. My date format doesn't have any breakpoints.

Comment: @Will_Panda `std::get_time(&when, "%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S");` should do, just without miliseconds

Comment: `strptime` [doesn't support milliseconds](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html).

By the way, what about just sscanf?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Visual C++ added C++ 11 support and get_time specifically in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @Mine I used std::get_time(&t, "%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S") but parsing fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the format of your string, it is fairly easy to parse it as follows (although a regex or `get_time` might be more elegant):

```
tm t;
t.tm_year = stoi(s.substr(0, 4));
t.tm_mon = stoi(s.substr(4, 2));
t.tm_mday = stoi(s.substr(6, 2));
t.tm_hour = stoi(s.substr(9, 2));
t.tm_min = stoi(s.substr(12, 2));
t.tm_sec = 0;
double sec = stod(s.substr(15));
```

Finding the time since the epoch can be done with [`mktime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime):

```
mktime(&t) + sec * 1000
```

Note that the fractional seconds need to be handled differently - unfortunately, [`tm` has only integer seconds](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/).

(See the full code [here](https://ideone.com/WFNfYK).)

---

**Edit**

As Mine and Panagiotis Kanavos correctly note in the comments, Visual C++ apparently supports `get_time` for quite a while, and it's much shorter with it (note that the fractional seconds need to be handled the same way, though).

Comment: Thank you. Yes I was planning to opt to this option in case I can't find an elegant solution.

Comment: @Will_Panda :-) I unfortunately agree - it is not the most elegant thing constructed; more like ugly brown duct-tape.

Comment: A duct-tape is a duct-tape nevertheless. :)

Comment: Except for the miliseconds part, `std::get_time(&when, "%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S");` looks cleaner.

Comment: @Mine I agree (also wrote that in the answer); note the question isn't tagged as c++11, though. The milliseconds are an inherent problem, BTW, as `tm` seems to have no sub-second field.

Comment: @AmiTavory Visual C++ added C++11 support and get_time specifically in 2010.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, where `get_time` exists, that's the way to go, then - I agree. Am not that familiar with Visual C++ (and it doesn't look like the question is tagged like it), so thanks for the info! Will update the answer.

Comment: The OP mentioned Windows. It's either Visual C++ or gcc. Some projects are stuck with ancient Borland or Microsoft compilers though (think 1998)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, I added your correct remark to the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mine It worked when the format is in like "2011.01.05-05:05:05" where there are delimiters in the date. But without delimiters parsing failed.

Comment: @AmiTavory The year should be the last two digits plus 100 right? Because we are taking time from Unix epoch. So 2016 becomes 116. (1900+116).

Comment: @Will_Panda I don't think so. Once the `tm` structure is properly set up (except for the seconds, which is a separate issue), [`mktime`  already does that for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979655/how-to-convert-a-time-into-epoch-time).

Comment: @Will_Panda One thing I've just noticed from the answer there is that the months seem 0 based, so you might want to pay attention to that if your input is 1 based.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. But the way i suggested worked. Anyways I am going to use this approach and hence I will accept this answer. :-)

Comment: @Will_Panda Oh, thanks for the comment (and the upvote)! I'll play around with it too to see what's happening. Good luck!

Comment: Nothing about mktime() using the locale timezone ?
As an example (not tested), it will not work if the locale timezone is "America/Montreal" and the tm contains UTC values.

Answer (score 6):

What about `std::sscanf`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    const char *str_time = "20160907-05:00:54.123";
    unsigned int year, month, day, hour, minute, second, miliseconds;

    if (std::sscanf(str_time, "%4u%2u%2u-%2u:%2u:%2u.%3u", &year, &month,
               &day, &hour, &minute, &second,&miliseconds) != 7)
    {
        std::cout << "Parse failed" << std::endl;
    } 
    else
    {
        std::cout << year << month << day << "-" << hour << ":" 
                  << minute << ":" << second << "." << miliseconds
                  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Output** ([ideone](https://ideone.com/bxVSyT)):
201697-5:0:54.123.

However, you should make sure the input is valid (for example, day can be in the range of [0,99]).

Comment: Yes. This works and you are right I have to make sure the input is valid. But I was looking for something more elegant rather than splitting the each element individually. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Too bad about no 3rd party libraries, because [here is one](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/date.h) (MIT license) that is just a single header, runs on linux and Windows, and handles the milliseconds seamlessly:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    date::sys_time<std::chrono::milliseconds> tp;
    std::istringstream in{"20160907-05:00:54.123"};
    date::parse(in, "%Y%m%d-%T", tp);
    std::cout << tp.time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
1473224454123
```

Error checking is done for you.  The stream will `fail()` if the date is invalid.

`date::sys_time<std::chrono::milliseconds>` is a type alias for `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::milliseconds>`.  I.e. it is from the family of `system_clock::time_point`, just `milliseconds` precision.

Fully documented:

https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html

Doesn't get much more elegant than this.

Comment: It looks like a great option. But unfortunately I can't use any.