# Converting date, time and UTC offset values to milliseconds since unix epoch?

Tags: c++, c, linux, datetime, epoch

I am working on a robotics project which has sensor data from different locations with millisecond precision (gps synchronised ntp to within 1ms).

How to convert historical date, time and UTC offset components into milliseconds since unix epoch? That is, all `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.mS +/-UTC offset` are available as individual integers and not a string.

The offset accounts for daylight savings so for example a timezone of UTC +1 will have a UTC offset of +2 during daylight savings.

There is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371527) however it dealt with a datetime in a string format with no UTC offset information.

The accepted answer from that post was to use `mktime` however in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979655/how-to-convert-a-time-into-epoch-time) a 60K+ rep user commented that:

> mktime will use your computer's locale to convert that date/time into GMT. If you do not want to have your local timezone subtracted, then use mkgmtime.

I've confirmed that `mktime` does perform timezone conversions which are dependent on the daylight savings flag `tm_isdst`. I don't have information whether or not the observations were taken during daylight savings or not, only their offset to UTC.

What is a robust way to convert historical datetimes with UTC offsets into milliseconds since unix epoch?

Comment: If you look to the accepted answer of the question you referred to, it deals with individual integers. It splits string to parts, converts them to integers and then works with them. Just drop the conversion part.

Comment: And perform a manual timezone adjustment of `unadjustedTime + timeZone * 3600` ? Is there a cleaner way to perform this?

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind, that there are half an hour time zones. So timeZone should not be measured in hours.

Comment: There are also quarter hour times zones.

Comment: What is an example `Tz`?  I.e. is this a timezone abbreviation?

Comment: The timezone `Tz` in the data is +/- int e.g. `+5` or `-3`.

Comment: Sorry, I have confused myself a significant amount. I have the UTC offset (which accounts for daylight savings) and not the timezone.

Comment: Use a library. Boost Date_time is one option.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you for your suggesting Boost.Date_Time, I had a look at it and could not find a method for using UTC offsets to get unix epoch. Would you recommend on manually subtracting the UTC offset from `local_date_time`, where the `local_date_time` was set using the unadjusted datetime values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [free, open-source C++11/14 header-only library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) which will do the job.  It is [fully documented](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), and portable across all C++11/14 implementations.  There is even a [video presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vwd3pduVGKY) of it.

```
#include "chrono_io.h"
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    istringstream in{"2016-10-10 23:48:59.456 -4"};
    sys_time<milliseconds> tp;
    int ih;
    in >> parse("%F %T", tp) >> ih;
    tp -= hours{ih};
    cout << tp.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
1476157739456ms
```

Which is the correct number of [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) milliseconds since the epoch.  If you need to include leap seconds, there are facilities for that at the above links, but that part is not header-only (requires using the [IANA timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones)).

This library is `<chrono>`-based.  In particular the type of `tp` is `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::milliseconds>`, but with prettier syntax.

If your input stream followed the standard UTC offset syntax of +/-hhmm instead of +/-[h]h, the code could be simplified to:

```
istringstream in{"2016-10-10 23:48:59.456 -0400"};
sys_time<milliseconds> tp;
in >> parse("%F %T %z", tp);
```

which would output the exact same value for `tp`.

```
1476157739456ms
```

This modified syntax is also supported:

```
istringstream in{"2016-10-10 23:48:59.456 -4:00"};
sys_time<milliseconds> tp;
in >> parse("%F %T %Ez", tp);
```

If you want the integral value of milliseconds, that is available with `<chrono>`'s `duration.count()` member function:

```
cout << tp.time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';

1476157739456
```

Any way you slice it, this is a few lines of type-safe code with no explicit conversion factors.

I noticed you tagged your question with both [c++] and [c].  This answer addresses only the C++ language.  C and C++ are two distinct languages, and if you must program in C, one of the other answers which program down at the C level of abstraction would be better.

For the curious, with any of these variants, if you just output `tp`:

```
cout << tp << '\n';
```

Then it outputs the expected UTC timestamp:

```
2016-10-11 03:48:59.456
```

Comment: Your talk was really good! :) 

The example compiles and runs however I receive a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` when running the line `in >> parse("%F %T", lt) >> ih;`. Am I missing something? I am compiling the example using `g++` with the flag `-std=c++11`.

Comment: The second example which contains `-0400` worked perfectly. Your library is excellent! Is there a way of creating a datetime in a similar way to how dates can be created? That is `auto x1 = year{y}/m/d;`. The reason I ask is that the year, month, day, etc are all `int`. The `make_zoned` function in your presentation looks like it might be able to take `int` values?.

Comment: The offset value I have is also not a timezone, but the actual offset from UTC at the time the sensor data was recorded. So there is no need to worry about day light saving changeovers where UTC can map to two local datetimes.

Comment: @rippling For the core dump, check `in.fail()` after the `parse`.  If true then `ih` is uninitialized.  Which version of gcc core dumped?  `-std=c++11` should be sufficient.

Comment: @rippling:  A datetime is a chrono::time_point, either `sys_time` for UTC, or `local_time` for local to-be-paired with a `time_zone`.  `auto x1 = sys_days{year{y}/m/d} + hours{h} + minutes{m} + seconds{s} + milliseconds{ms}` (to whatever precision you want).  Use `local_days` instead of `sys_days` if you want a local time instead of a UTC time.

Comment: @rippling:  As a temporary work-around for the segfault use `%H:%M:%S` in place of `%T`.  Debugging it now...

Comment: Bug fixed in https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/commit/cfa55850c764b76d2de5be0034b9beba3dcc02c7  Thank you for the bug report!

Comment: Thank you for your help! `auto x1 = sys_days{year{y}/m/d} + hours{h} + minutes{mins} + seconds{s} + milliseconds{ms} - minutes{offset};` then `x1.time_since_epoch().count()` is a beautiful and clean solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the timezone in terms of hours +/- UTC, you can first use `mktime` (as the linked answer describes) to convert the date/time to seconds since the epoch.  Then, add/subtract the timezone difference.

EDIT:

Since the `mktime` function assumes the given time is for the current timezone, you'll need to shift the result by that amount as well.

First, run the `tzset()` function.  This sets two global variables: `timezone` which is the number of seconds the current time is behind GMT, and `daylight` which indicates whether daylight savings is in effect.

```
struct tm my_time;
// populate fields
int my_tz;
// set to timezone in question as seconds ahead of UTC
time_t t = mktime(&my_time);
t += timezone;
if (daylight) {
    t -= 3600;
}
t -= my_tz;
```

Comment: I have the timezone in +/-UTC. I updated the post to also highlight what I read by respectable user (60K+ rep) about `mktime` automatically converting the datetime to UTC from the current timezone? Is this correct?

Comment: [`mktime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1y53h2a.aspx) "Convert the local time to a calendar value."

Answer (score 0):

If you look to the accepted answer of the question you referred to, it deals with individual integers. It splits string to parts, converts them to integers and then works with them. Just drop the conversion part.

```
tm t;
// Fill tm_sec, tm_min, tm_hour and so on
return (mktime(&t) - tz * SECONDS_IN_TIMEZONE) * 1000 + milliseconds
```

If timezone is an integer, you can multiply it by number of seconds in timezone and **substract** if from the time. +4 zone means that time is 4 hours greater then UTC. Also note that not all time zones have integral number of hours. So you may want to store timezone in seconds/milliseconds or at least minutes.