# C++ How To Convert String YYYYMMDD To TimeStamp

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a program that gets installed on my laptop to a json file.

I retrieve the date of the installed program from registry and I would like to convert that date to a timestamp.

This is my code :

```
HKEY hUninstKey = NULL;
HKEY hAppKey = NULL;

WCHAR InstallDate[1024];
WCHAR *sRoot = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall";
long lResult = ERROR_SUCCESS;
DWORD dwType = KEY_ALL_ACCESS;
DWORD dwBufferSize = 0;

//Open the "Uninstall" key.
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sRoot, 0, KEY_READ, &hUninstKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{

}

for (DWORD dwIndex = 0; lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS; dwIndex++)
{
    //Enumerate all sub keys...
    dwBufferSize = sizeof(sAppKeyName);
    if ((lResult = RegEnumKeyEx(hUninstKey, dwIndex, sAppKeyName,
        &dwBufferSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        //Open the sub key.

        if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sSubKey, 0, KEY_READ, &hAppKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            RegCloseKey(hAppKey);
            RegCloseKey(hUninstKey);

        }

        //Get the display name value from the application's sub key.
        dwBufferSize = sizeof((RegQueryValueEx(hAppKey, L"InstallDate", NULL, &dwType, (unsigned char*)InstallDate, &dwBufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS))
        {

            // Display Date Of Installed Program
            const TCHAR* xInstallDate = (TCHAR*)InstallDate;
            char DateInstall[MAX_LENGTH + 200];
            wcstombs_s(&nNumCharConverted, DateInstall, MAX_LENGTH + 200,
                xInstallDate, MAX_LENGTH + 200);


            file << "\"',date='" << DateInstall  << endl;               
        }
        else {
            //Display name value doe not exist, this application was probably uninstalled.
        }


        RegCloseKey(hAppKey);
    }
}

RegCloseKey(hUninstKey);
```

Could anyone please help with my code?

Comment: what happens when you run it? What errors do you get, or what unexpected behaviour?

Comment: when i run it i get date='20191216' and i want to get it with timeStamp Like date='1576454400'

Comment: So you want to convert a date time string to epoch time? If so, this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979655/how-to-convert-a-time-into-epoch-time

Comment: Make a small program that only does the conversion. The bulk of the code here is just noise that's helping the bug hide. Use [mcve] as inspiration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a time into epoch time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979655/how-to-convert-a-time-into-epoch-time)

Comment: A time point is always relative to a particular clock. You never mentioned, which clock you want to reference.

Comment: @KBriggs yes Thank You. it's working

Comment: UNIX time is not a clock that's [commonly used in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/about-time). Yes, it *"works"*, in that it produces a value. But that value isn't of much use in Windows.

Comment: Why you have provided such complex example. Code which manipulates windows registries obscures your actual problem.

Comment: `dwBufferSize = sizeof((RegQueryValueEx(hAppKey, L"InstallDate", NULL, &dwType, (unsigned char*)InstallDate, &dwBufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS))` WAT?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the usage of `std::chrono::parse`. It converts string streams into chrono objects which represent time.

This is the documentation of std::chrono::parse: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/parse

This is a relevant question on SO (you are possibly a duplicate): [How to parse a date string into a c++11 std::chrono time_point or similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021388/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-a-c11-stdchrono-time-point-or-similar)

Comment: `std::chrono::parse` is C++20. It is to early to use it.

Comment: C++11-compatible preview of `std::chrono::parse` is here: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date